# How do I get a folder name using a wildcard and check for it's uniqueness

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to move a series of file into different folder based on their ID, but I want to make sure that the folder I'm moving the file to exists and is unique

The folders have a matching ID as the first part of their name, but also have a description in their name (the ID *should* be unique, but I want to guard against that exception) :

```
0123-app1
4567-app2
2020-app3
0123-shouldntbehere
```

I want to move file with ID `4567` to the directory `4567-app2`.

Since the description is in the name, I need to use a wildcard to find the right folder. Right now I tried echoing the name in a variable, but it doesn't help me check if it's unique or if it exists.

```
APP_PATH=`echo $APP_ID*`
```

What would suggest I use to find the right folder and validate that it's unique ?

Thanks

Comment: Still not really sure what you are trying to do but you could use this to check for dup folders `for i in */;do echo ${i/-*/};done | uniq -d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I implemented it was with an `if` statement with an error code check. The `[ -d ...]` will generate an error if more than one parameter (folder name) are passed when the wildcard is exploded **or** if the files doesn't exist. The `ls` in the `else` allows us to know which case brought us here (if multiple folder exists, the return code will be `0`)

```
if [ -d ${ID}* ] 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Folder exists and is unique"
else
    ls ${ID}* >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "No folder exists starting with ${ID}"
    else
        echo "More than one folder starting with ${ID}"
    fi
fi
```